# Why can't i see the inserted data from user input?

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

When the user presses Register button, the details he input will be saved into the database but it doesnt show anything.

Is there something wrong with my code? Why can't i see the data i inserted into the database? It doesnt crashes or something.

DBAdapter

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBAdapter
{
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_FNAME = "fname";
    public static final String KEY_LNAME = "lname";
    public static final String KEY_MNAME = "mname";
    public static final String KEY_CONTACTNUM = "contactNum";
    public static final String KEY_LICENSE = "license";
    public static final String KEY_USER = "username";
    public static final String KEY_PASS = "password";
    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "sampleForFinals";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "drivers";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "create table drivers (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + "fname text not null, lname text not null, "
                    + "mname text not null, contactNum text not null," +
                    "license text not null, username text not null, password text not null);";

    private final Context context;

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
                              int newVersion)
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion
                    + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS drivers");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    //---opens the database---
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    //---closes the database---
    public void close()
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    //---insert a driver's information into the database---
    public long insertDriver(String fname, String lname, String mname, String contactNum, String license, String user, String pass)
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_FNAME, fname);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LNAME, lname);
        initialValues.put(KEY_MNAME, mname);
        initialValues.put(KEY_CONTACTNUM, contactNum);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LICENSE, license);
        initialValues.put(KEY_USER, user);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PASS, pass);
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }
}
```

Register

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.ftlibrary.Fit;

public class Register extends Activity {

    EditText firstname,lastname, middlename, contactNum, license, username, password;
    Button register;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        Fit.FitSetClientKey("SZIERAINE1527");
        Fit.FitSetAppName("sampleForFinals");

        firstname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_firstname);
        lastname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_lastname);
        middlename = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_middlename);
        contactNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_contactNumber);
        license = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_license);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_username);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);
        register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_register);

        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                    DBAdapter    db = new DBAdapter(Register.this);

                    String fname = firstname.getText().toString();
                    String lname = lastname.getText().toString();
                    String mname = middlename.getText().toString();
                    String contact = contactNum.getText().toString();
                    String plate = license.getText().toString();
                    String user = username.getText().toString();
                    String pass = password.getText().toString();

                    db.open();

                    long id = db.insertDriver(fname, lname, mname, contact, plate, user, pass);

                    db.close();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Why can't i see any record in the database? TT TT

Comment: You are probably going to want a db.commit() before closing or whatever the equivalent is for java/android

Comment: have you checked your xml? double check the name of your button or editTexts on your XML file.

Comment: @dranrebdino  i did. Data really just isnt inserted. also, the table is not created. I dont understand why. Im thinking maybe im not connected to the cloud database but it isnt. Its been 14 hours working on this problem

Answer (score 0):

The insertion of data into `database` is working fine.

The issue is because it's not specified how the data is gonna be displayed or received from the `database`. You need to query `database` to get the inserted data.

---

Use query method of `SQLiteDatabase` class. This worked for me:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        // retrieve data from cursor
        String fname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_FNAME));
        String lname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_LNAME));
        // ...
        
        // do something with the retrieved data
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

The query is called on `db` obj and returns the `Cursor`. It contains the data.

The `moveToFirst` is called the `Cursor` obj.

The `do-while` loop is used to iterate over all rows in the obj, `getString` receiving the data from the column.

Customise the query to retrieve specific data using `selection`, `selectionArgs`, `groupBy`, `having`, `orderBy` but also limit parameters.

---

If the errors still persist when you're inserting data to the `database`, add error handling to the insertion code to check if data is corectly inserted or if there are any exceptions during the process.

###### This will help you identify any issue with `database` insertion.